# C# winform default template

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, templates

I just created a windows form application with labels,textbox and buttons and put some style on it just want to know if i can save that as a default template so i can reuse it again and again, i know how and tried to make a user controls but can you do it on a whole form like Open>>New project >> My windows form default template.Thanks in advance!

Note I'm using Windows Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Template… sounds like a Class?  Make a Form Class with your desired components.

Comment: So, you created an object called `form1 : Form`. Now, create another one `form2 : form1` - there we go.

Comment: To create a template for a Form you need to look at Item Templates: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tsyyf0yh(v=vs.120).aspx

Comment: Thanks @PeterBons this is exactly what I'm looking for.